# One of custom post types, added through a loop, does not show on dashboard

Tags: wordpress

Hello everyone and thank you in advance,

I created custom post types using a loop but one of them does not show on dashboard. Only Comeleon annonces appeares and when i remove from array $agencies the line with comeleon, no custom post type shows. What did i do wrong?

```
<?php
add_action("init", "create_post_type");
function create_post_type(){
        $agencies = [
            ["name" => "comeleon", "label" => "Comeleon"],  
            ["name" => "samsung", "label" => "Samsung"],  
        ];
        foreach ($agencies as $agency) {
            $cptName = $agency["name"]."_annonces";
            $label = $agency["label"];
            register_post_type(
                $cptName,
                array(
                    "labels" => array(
                        "name" => esc_html($label." annonces", "regina"),
                        "singular_name" => esc_html($label." annonce", "regina"),
                        "add_new" => esc_html("Ajouter nouvelle", "regina"),
                        "add_new_item" => esc_html("Ajouter nouvelle annonce", "regina"),
                        "edit" => esc_html("Modifier", "regina"),
                        "edit_item" => esc_html("Modifier annonce", "regina"),
                        "new_item" => esc_html("Nouvelle annonce", "regina"),
                        "view" => esc_html("Voir annonce", "regina"),
                        "view_item" => esc_html("Voir annonce", "regina"),
                        "search_items" => esc_html("Chercher annonce", "regina"),
                        "not_found" => esc_html("Aucune annonce trouvée", "regina"),
                        "not_found_in_trash" => esc_html("Aucune annonce trouvée dans la poubelle", "regina"),
                    ),
                    "public" => true,
                    "capability_type" => array($agency["name"]."_annonce", $cptName),
                    "map_meta_cap" => true,
                    "hierarchical" => true,
                    "has_archive" => true,
                    "supports" => array(
                        "title",
                        "editor",
                        'custom-fields'
                        )
                ) );
        }
?>
```

I have created these roles:

```
    register_activation_hook(__FILE__, "reg_activation");
       function reg_activation()
        {
            $agencies = [
                ["name" => "comeleon", "label" => "Comeleon"],
                ["name" => "samsung", "label" => "Samsung"],
            ];
            $caps = [
                "read" => true,
                "edit_posts" => true,
                "upload_files" => true,
            ];
            foreach ($agencies as $agency) {
                add_role("admin_".$agency["name"], "Admin ".$agency["label"], $caps);
                add_role("contributor_".$agency["name"], "Contributeur ".$agency["label"], $caps);
            }
        }
        add_action("admin_init", 'reg_add_role_caps', 999);
    function reg_add_role_caps (){
        $agencies = [
            ["name" => "comeleon", "label" => "Comeleon"],
            ["name" => "samsung", "label" => "Samsung"],
        ];
                    
                    foreach ($agencies as $agency) {
                        $cptName = $agency["name"]."_annonces";
                    // role admin
                    $roleAdmin = get_role("admin_".$agency["name"]);
                    if (null === $roleAdmin) {
                        return;
                    }
                    $roleAdmin->add_cap("read");
                    $roleAdmin->add_cap("read_".$cptName);
                    $roleAdmin->add_cap("read_private_".$cptName);
                    $roleAdmin->add_cap("edit_".$cptName);
                    $roleAdmin->add_cap("edit_others_".$cptName);
                    $roleAdmin->add_cap("edit_published_".$cptName);
                    $roleAdmin->add_cap("publish_".$cptName);
                    $roleAdmin->add_cap("delete_others_".$cptName);
                    $roleAdmin->add_cap("delete_private_".$cptName);
                    $roleAdmin->add_cap("delete_published_".$cptName);
    
    
                    // role contributor
                    $roleContributor = get_role("contributor_".$agency["name"]);
                    if (null === $roleContributor) {
                        return;
                    }
                    $roleContributor->add_cap("read");
                    $roleContributor->add_cap("read_".$cptName);
                    $roleContributor->add_cap("read_private_".$cptName);
                    $roleContributor->add_cap("edit_".$cptName);              
                    $roleContributor->add_cap("edit_published_".$cptName);
                    $roleContributor->add_cap("publish_".$cptName);
                    $roleContributor->add_cap("delete_private_".$cptName);
                    $roleContributor->add_cap("delete_published_".$cptName);
    
    
        }
    }
```

And i can see those custom post types from their dashboards but not from the dashboard of administrator, just one: Comeleon annonces

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
"capability_type" => array($agency["name"]."_annonce", $cptName),
```

With this

```
"capability_type" => 'post',
```

Complete code.

```
add_action("init", "create_post_type");
function create_post_type(){
    $agencies = [
        ["name" => "comeleon", "label" => "Comeleon"],  
        ["name" => "samsung", "label" => "Samsung"],  
    ];
    foreach ($agencies as $agency) {
        $cptName = $agency["name"]."_annonces";
        $label = $agency["label"];
        register_post_type(
            $cptName,
            array(
                "labels" => array(
                    "name" => esc_html($label." annonces", "regina"),
                    "singular_name" => esc_html($label." annonce", "regina"),
                    "add_new" => esc_html("Ajouter nouvelle", "regina"),
                    "add_new_item" => esc_html("Ajouter nouvelle annonce", "regina"),
                    "edit" => esc_html("Modifier", "regina"),
                    "edit_item" => esc_html("Modifier annonce", "regina"),
                    "new_item" => esc_html("Nouvelle annonce", "regina"),
                    "view" => esc_html("Voir annonce", "regina"),
                    "view_item" => esc_html("Voir annonce", "regina"),
                    "search_items" => esc_html("Chercher annonce", "regina"),
                    "not_found" => esc_html("Aucune annonce trouvée", "regina"),
                    "not_found_in_trash" => esc_html("Aucune annonce trouvée dans la poubelle", "regina"),
                ),
                "public" => true,
                "capability_type" => 'post',
                "map_meta_cap" => true,
                "hierarchical" => true,
                "has_archive" => true,
                "supports" => array(
                    "title",
                    "editor",
                    'custom-fields'
                    )
            ) 
        );
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly for administator, but now they dont show up for roles that i created in their dashboards

Comment: Which roles you have created? please put details in question.